# Snakes on a plane

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry

A *sleeping bag for a baby snake in $d$ dimensions* ([no, really](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00454-001-0011-5)) is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$ which can cover (via translation and rotation) every (piecewise-smooth for concreteness) curve of unit length in $\mathbb{R}^d$. For $d=2$ this was [posed by Moser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moser%27s_worm_problem), and Stewart asked about the $d=3$ case; the above-linked paper by Hastad/Linusson/Wastlund constructs low-volume sleeping bags in all dimensions $\ge 3$.

A couple of my colleagues and I were talking about the relationship (if any) between the $d=2$ and $d=3$ versions of the problem. Roughly speaking, suppose $X$ is a "reasonably small" $3$-sleeping bag; must some cross section of $X$ be a $2$-sleeping bag? We discussed it for a bit, and it's not obvious to us which of the following (if either) is actually stringent: requiring that *some cross section is* a sleeping bag, or that *no cross section is* a sleeping bag.

To be precise:

> Let $v$ be the infimum of the volumes of $3$-sleeping bags. Is it the case that, for every $\epsilon>0$,
>
> - there is some $3$-sleeping bag with volume $\le v+\epsilon$ which does contain a $2$-sleeping bag as a cross section? (EDIT: As Will Sawin points out below, in order to avoid a trivial answer to this question we need to further require that the $3$-sleeping bag not have any subset which is also a $3$-sleeping bag but does not have any $2$-sleeping bag cross-sections.)
> - there is some $3$-sleeping bag with volume $\le v+\epsilon$ which does not contain a $2$-sleeping bag as a cross section?

Comment: An interesting question, but +1 for the title alone.

Comment: Can't you always add the product of a $2$-sleeping bag with an interval of length $\epsilon to an arbitrary $3$-sleeping bag to get a positive answer to the first question?

Comment: @WillSawin Good point - I meant to require that it not have a sub-$3$-sleeping-bag which doesn't have a $2$-sleeping-bag cross-section. Fixed!